# Split a string at a specific character in SQL

Tags: string, postgresql, split, sql

In my SQL statement I have to extract a substring from a string at the character '_'. Strings can be for example 'A_XXX' 'AB_XXX' 'ABC_XXXX', so the extracted substrings should be like 'A' 'AB' 'ABC'.

In Oracle this is easy with the substr() and instr() functions:

```
select substr('AB_XXX', 1, instr('AB_XXX', '_')-1) as substring
from dual;
```

The result would be:

```
SUBSTRING
------------------------
AB
```

I need this query to check if a specific substring is in an array of strings.

The whole query would look like:

```
select 'AB_XXX' from dual
where (instr('ABC_AB_A', substr('AB_XXX', 1, instr('AB_XXX', '_')-1))>0);
```

Is there a way to write it in a SQL standard-compliant way?

If PostgreSQL provides an alternative function, it also helps. The rest could be solved with e.g. IN.

The really important part is to get the substring.

Comment: I don't think there is something in the SQL standard for this. But in Oracle it would probably be easier using regular expressions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your second example is a bit confusing because you are mixing `'ABC_AB_A'` and `'AB_XXX'` not sure if that is typo.

But if you just want all characters before the first `_` then the following works in Postgres:

```
left(col, strpos(col, '_') - 1)
```

or using a regular expression:

```
substring(col from '([A-Z]+)(_{1})')
```

You can use a regular expression in Oracle as well:

```
regexp_substr(col, '([A-Z]+)(_{1})', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
```

Postgres' `substring` function always returns the first capturing group of the regex whereas in Oracle you can specify the group you want: that is the last parameter to the `regexp_substr()` function.

SQLFiddle for Oracle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b138c/1
SQLFiddle for Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4b2bb/1

Comment: The `left` solution will remove the last character of the string if the delimiter character is not present. The `split_part` function as shown by @totymedli is a better alternative in this particular case (or the regex solution).

Answer (score 47):

### tl;dr

Use [`split_part`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-split_part/) which was purposely built for this:

```
split_part(string, '_', 1)
```

### Explanation

Quoting this [PostgreSQL API docs](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-split_part/):

> `SPLIT_PART()` function splits a string on a specified delimiter and returns the nth substring.

The 3 parameters are the string to be split, the delimiter, and the part/substring number (starting from 1) to be returned.

So if you have a field named `string` that contains stuff like `AB_XXX` and you would like to get everything before `_`, then you split by that and get the first part/substring: `split_part(string, '_', 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

The standard SQL string functions are described at:
[SQL String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL).

There's a `substring` function that can extract contents directly, without having to nest function calls. It's detailed in [Pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) as:

> The substring function with three parameters, **substring(string from
>   pattern for escape-character)**, provides extraction of a substring that
>   matches an SQL regular expression pattern. As with SIMILAR TO, the
>   specified pattern must match the entire data string, or else the
>   function fails and returns null. To indicate the part of the pattern
>   that should be returned on success, the pattern must contain two
>   occurrences of the escape character followed by a double quote (").
>   The text matching the portion of the pattern between these markers is
>   returned.

In your case:

```
select substring('AB_XX' from '#"%#"#_%' for '#');
```

Result:

```
 substring 
-----------
 AB
(1 row)
```

The syntax is a bit weird, especially since `_` is a wildcard for a single character so it has to be quoted, but it's the SQL standard.

For the syntax that more people use, consider `regexp_replace()` or a similar function working with POSIX regular expressions.