# Find specific characters, extract the sentence, and place it into a new column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column which has the long sentences. There are several semicolons in the sentences. I would like to extract the words/sentences of the first semicolon. In MS Excel, Left and Find functions can be used. As I am new to the Postgres, I am struggling to make it with various kind of string function in Postgres (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

e.g.

```
my_column
dark roast Colombian coffee; the favor is tasty; the smell is light
```

expected result

```
my_column                                                            |  new_column
dark roast Colombian coffee; the favor is tasty; the smell is light  | dark roast Columbian coffee
```

Comment: Your problem is easier to solve. But please properly format you question. So people can easily understand your expected result. Please use Edit button format your question.

Comment: Does @totymedli answer in this question, answer your question? [Split string at specific character SQL-Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895896/split-string-at-specific-character-sql-standard)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regular expression or using pattern matching of substring function. Example:

```
select trim(substring(my_column from '%#"%;#"%' for '#'), ';');

update yourtable 
set new_column = trim(substring(my_column from '%#"%;#"%' for '#'), ';');
```

There is also a simple way. This is split_part function.

Examples:

```
split_part(my_column , ';', 1); Result => 'dark roast Colombian coffee'
split_part(my_column , ';', 2); Result => 'the favor is tasty' 
split_part(my_column , ';', 3); Result => 'the smell is light'
```